# Check admin login on my django app

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-apps

I have created a django app and have linked to the admin index page by modifying base.html. However, the link of the app is accessible directly as well.

Can I check on the page or in the views.py of my app if the user is logged in to the django admin or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@staff_member_required` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u:u.is_staff, login_url='/foo/')
def staff_view(request..):
    ...
```