# Checking if admin is logged in

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check if current logged in user is admin then allow them to access admin page else return to homepage.

heres my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from teacher.models import users


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print (user)
            messages.success(request, "You have successfully Logged In.")
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "You have entered invalid credentials. Please try again")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/login.html')
    

    

def admin(request):
    user = users.objects.get(category = 'admin')
    if user:
        return render(request, 'main/admin.html')

    elif Exception:
        return render(request, 'main/home.html')
```

heres my models.py

```
class users(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    hpassword = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default= "teacher")
```

I have tried using different method of query. But I end up getting error page as 'user matching query doesn't exist'. Also it doesn't check if user is logged in or not. Even if user is not logged in it returns to admin page.

Comment: You want to check if `request.user` is an admin, not whether you have any admins in the database… https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: for my case admin is a category who gets my own admin page not django admin page. This admin is completely unrelated to django admin. I have added models now for better understanding

Comment: That doesn't negate anything about what I said or what the documentation says. You want to inspect `request.user` for what category it is, not select all users with a specific category from your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you search about decorators?  have a look [Check admin login on my django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362857/check-admin-login-on-my-django-app)

and  for dashboard access check [Django login Decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) you can redirect the user back to login pageif not logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
  ...
```

for 2nd 'user matching query doesn't exist'.
check if you have a database table. make sure have run migrations
and use Try Exception

```
try:     
    user = users.objects.get(category = 'admin')     
    if user:         
        return render(request, 'main/admin.html')    
except Exception as e:     
       return render(request, 'main/home.html')
```

Comment: for second error I want that error to happen but redirect to home page instead of throwing error. Thats why I tried used Exception and Valueerror

Comment: so if you have used Exception, what is the issue now?

Comment: exception doesn't exactly help and still shows error.. I don't want that error but instead redirect only.

Comment: so did you used redirection in Exception?

`except Exception as e:
         return redirect(URL) `

Comment: Yes. I have also tried `elif Exception:             return redirect(URL)`. Assuming the method you posted didn't work first

Comment: is there only one admin in the database? and the other thing share error details as well.

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 admin in database.  This admin is different from django admin. This admin is my personal admin coming from category in django which I want to verify in first place. Error is "users matching query does not exist.", Which is what i want to receive if logged in user has no category admin, but instead of error page redirect to homepage.

Comment: users matching query does not exist means you dont have any such data in database. confim if you have..  and try  this
`get_object_or_404(users, category='admin')`
instead of  old query.. and let me know .. make sure you have data in databse

Comment: method works and returns 404 instead of main function when not in database. but still doesn't redirect

Comment: `use try:
    user = users.objects.get(category = 'admin')
    if user:
        return render(request, 'main/admin.html')
   except Exception as e:
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')

`

try this.

Comment: Great. This was my goal as well... I wasn't putting indent with try. That must have caused it. Thanks for help. If you update your answer I can accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217817/discussion-between-jahanzeb-nawaz-and-sahilm).

Answer (score 2):

default User class in django have a boolean field called **'is_superuser'** which define is user admin or not.

Comment: The user admin here is not an admin account to access django but a admin user for moderation. with various abilities such as create user, update user, view reports and activity of other user. I have added models page. You can check user category there